# Check If Part of an array exists in larger array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to detect if a smaller Array is is in a larger array.

Legend:

```
$user = Larger Array 
$TMP = Smaller Array
```

Example:

```
$TMP  =  
Array
(
    [user] => Array
    (
        [timezone] => -8
    )

)

$user =

Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => example
        )

    [userid] => 275
    [user] => Array
    (
        [email] => thisisatest10@gmail.com
        [id] => 48339
        [timezone] => Array
            (
            )

    )
)
```

In this case I would want a script that would return false.

But if timezone -8 was already in user I would want it to be true

I tried already:

```
$isSubset = 0 == count(array_diff($TMP, $user));
```

Comment: if `($TMP['user']['timezone']==$user['user']['timezone']){ ..}` ??

Comment: This will not work, as $TMP and $user are automatically generated and can change the value I am looking to identify.

Comment: Why not just compare what you want to compare?

```array_diff($TMP['user']['timezone'], $user['timezone']);```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function that checks that every key and leaf values in the smaller array exist in the larger array

```
function is_subset($smaller,$larger) {
    foreach($smaller as $k => $v) {
        if(!array_key_exists($k,$larger))
            return false;

        if(!is_array($v)) {
            if($v == $larger[$k])
                continue;
            else return false;            
        }
        else if(!is_subset($v,$larger[$k]))
            return false;
    }  
    return true;
}

$smaller = array('user' => array('timezone' => 2));
$larger = array('one' => 1,'user' => array('timezone' => 1));
var_dump(is_subset($smaller,$larger)); // false

$smaller = array('user' => array('timezone' => 1));
$larger = array('one' => 1,'user' => array('timezone' => 1));
var_dump(is_subset($smaller,$larger)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly compare from base array for effenciency

```
 function checksub($arr,$subarr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
        if($value==$subarr)
           return true;
        else{
            if(is_array($value)){
                return checksub($value,$subarr);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$array=array("a"=>1,"b"=>2,array("x"=>array("some","data","z"=>"w")));
$sub=array("x"=>array("some","data","z"=>"w"));
$nosub=array("x"=>array("some","data","z"=>"changed"));
$sub2=array("some","data","z"=>"w");
var_dump(checksub($array,$sub));
var_dump(checksub($array,$sub2));
var_dump(checksub($array,$nosub));
```